# in shiny, I am using multiple selectinputs to update the dataset but reactivety is not working properly?

Tags: r, shiny

New to R, now I am working on shiny app that include several select input, most of them i need to add "All" to enable the use to control whole outputs.
but it is not working. here is the code. my request is how to make the data frame update with each selection accordingly i will be able to plot any variables

```
 library(shiny)
 library(dplyr)
 library(plotly)
 library(tidyverse)
 brand<-mutate(mtcars,brand=substr(mtcars$model,1,4))

 shinyUI(fluidPage(
 titlePanel("mtcars"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  sliderInput("bins", "cost", min = 0,max = 10000,value = 1000),
  selectInput("f1","brand",choices=unique(mtcars$m),selected = "Merc"),
  selectInput("f2","model",choices=NULL),
  selectInput("f3","cyl",choices= c("All",unique(mtcars$cyl)),selected = "All"),
  selectInput("f4","hp",choices=c("All", unique(mtcars$hp)),selected = "All"),
  selectInput("f5","vs",choices=c("All", unique(mtcars$vs)),selected = "All"),
  selectInput("f6","gear",choices=c("All", unique(mtcars$gear)),selected = "All")),
  mainPanel(
  plotlyOutput("Test2", height = "250px"),
  plotlyOutput("Test3", height = "250px")
   )
 ) 
  )

 server<-function(input,output,session){
 observe({
print(input$brand)
df2<-brand%>%filter(brand==input$f1)
updateSelectInput(session,"f2","model",choices=unique(df2$model))
print(df2)
})
observe({
df3<-reactive({
 if(input$f3=="All"){df2}
  else {df3<-df2%>%filter(cyl==input$f3)
  updateSelectInput(session,"f3","cyl",choices=unique(df3$cyl))}
  print(df3)
})
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
  plot_ly(df3, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt)
})
})}
```